# Set constraint params for CardView inside the ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I need to apply some display configuration programmatically in Kotlin to a card view (because the problem is  i cannot define it in xml right away)

Here is this configuration in xml (which i want to be able to set identical programmatically if possible)

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/resultCard"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35">

       //some other Views inside this CardView 
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Is it possible to achive same configuration by coding it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same configuration in Kotlin, you could try:

```
val resultCard = findViewById(R.id.resultCard)
val params = resultCard.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
params.apply {
   startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
   endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
   topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
   bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
   horizontalBias = .5f
   verticalBias = .35f
}
```